# Updating contents of a DIV periodically from php not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, mobile

I'm trying to update contents of a DIV every second using the following code:

```
...
var timer = setInterval (check,1000);
function check(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "check.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Dynamic content is produced by a php page on the same server, in which for testing purpose I wrote this code:

```
...
Currently playing song number:
&lt;?php
echo (" ");
echo (rand(5,15)); 
?&gt;
...
```

It seems to work fine when I open the page from Chrome, but It's not working on mobile devices (I'm using Huawei P30 pro). Are there any restrictions on use of xhttp requests on mobile devices or can you spot any mistakes on the code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had edited the script.js source of the page without changing the name and apparently my phone had held in it's temp memory the previous version of the script. That's why it wasn't working